# using v-model in a v-for directive to create a new data object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to create an items object with a v-for directive in the following way:

```
<v-row v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:key="index">
            <v-col cols="12" md="4">
              <v-autocomplete
                v-model="item.product_uid"
                :items="product_list"
                item-text="[attributes][name]"
                item-value="id"
                label="Product name"
                outlined
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" md="4">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="item.qty"
                label="Quantity"
                outlined
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12" md="4">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="item.net_unit_price"
                label="Unit price"
                outlined
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
          <v-col>
            <v-btn rounded color="primary" dark @click="addItem()">Add</v-btn>
          </v-col>

data () {
      return {
        items: [],
        product_list: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addItem: function () {
        this.items.push({ product_uid: '', qty: '', net_unit_price: '',  });
      }
}
```

How can I get the "Unit price" value (product_list[attributes][price]) based on the selected "Product name" from the product_list object and than add it to the new items array?

The product_list object come from a http call from the server and I'd like to use these datas as a default value in the form and - if necessary - change the values and add them all to the new item object.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are trying to loop over items which is empty. Then you are trying to click on "Add" which push item to items. But you can't click "Add" because your items is empty. Most probably you should loop over product_list and not over items.

Comment: With the "Add" button I insert empty lines what I fill with values from the product_list object. My goal is if I choose a product from the product_list the Unit price field update with the matching value from the same product_list object.

Comment: I understand that moment, but you can't loop over items and add/delete it with "Add" because you will not be able to see that list because items is empty, so your "Add" button can't be rendered. You should loop over product_list. Maybe, I missed something.

Comment: I was confused by code indentation. I didn't see closing </v-row> before "Add" button. Looping over items make sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to "autocomplete" the quantity and unit price when choosing an item from the autocomplete list. So here's a sample. Let's say your api data looks like:

```js
product_list: [
  {product_uid: 1, name: 'name1', qty: 1, net_unit_price: 2},
  {product_uid: 2, name: 'name2', qty: 2, net_unit_price: 3},
  {product_uid: 3, name: 'name3', qty: 3, net_unit_price: 4}
],
```

Then remove the `v-model` and `item-value` from your autocomplete, and instead add `return-object`, so that we get the complete object from the autocomplete to use. Add the vuetify autocomplete event `change`, so that we can pass the object chosen and the index so that we can patch the value to your array:

Template:

```html
<v-autocomplete 
  :items="product_list"
  item-text="name" <!-- add correct prop -->
  label="Product name"
  outlined
  return-object <!-- add this and below -->
  @change="setValue(index, $event)"
></v-autocomplete>
```

So now when an item is chosen from the autocomplete, we call `setValue`, and we patch the correct values for it:

```js
setValue: function(index, item) {
  // if you want the complete object, else choose which props you want
  this.$set(this.items, index, { ... item })
}
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/KKwrdvQ?editors=1010)**

Comment: It looks nice, thanks a lot! I cant try it yet, but I wonder this solution also works if the product_list and the items objects has different structure?

Comment: if they have different structure no... that is why I added those two comments: `add correct prop` and `if you want the complete object, else choose which props you want` to cover this scenario also. I would assume that the id is always unique and the both lists should have objects with the same id, even though other props would have different names. But try it out, and if you run into a specific issue with code, just shout out and I'll try to help :)

Comment: So if the object properties do not match, instead of `this.$set(this.items, index, { ... item })` you can do... `this.$set(this.items, index, { product_uid: item.myProductUidPropertyName, qty: item.myProductQtyPropertyName, net_unit_price: item.myUnitPricePropertyName })` You get the point :)

Comment: Thanks for your help again! I'll try it and hope I cant bother you again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you should use `computed` property as noticed at documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html .

Also your `product_list` is empty. Before getting `product_list[attributes][price]` you should add something to it or get filtered result with help of computed properties or something else. Also, I don't understand what you are trying to do with that line of code `:items="product_list"` You are trying to set the same value to the `items` property of all components.

It's hard to understand what exactly you want to do, but probably, also you will need some kind of filter methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've edit my post to make it more understandable.

Comment: I have added a comment to your question but still my answer about playing with computed property is the way to go if I understand right after your changing.